# select query and join using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I have a table that contains **specialization id** that is a **foreign key** for the specialization table that contain **specialization_id** and **specialization_name**

I want to query  the `specialization_name` that have the same id in user table as in the specialization table.

Can anyone help me?

This what I start with but I think it is wrong

```
 $spec="";
 $sql = mysql_query("
            SELECT  
                specialization_name 
            FROM 
                user, specialization 
            WHERE 
                u.specialization=s.specialization_id 
            AND user_id='$id' 
        ") or die("the query from table specialization did not work");
```

Comment: be careful with sql injection..

Comment: And please note that mysql_* is deprecated. It is better to start using mysqli_*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  
    specialization_name 
FROM 
    user u 
INNER JOIN specialization s 
    ON u.specialization=s.specialization_id 
WHERE 
    user_id='$id'
```

And as Gonzalo well pointed out make sure you escape you inputs (in this case `$id`)

Also your query should work if you assign alias `u` for `user` table and `s` for `specialization` table